# Solidworks flow simulation temperature drop

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer, simulation, temperature, fluid

Using Soldiworks flow simulation, I want to calculate the temperature drop of water (40 degrees) which flows in 10 m steel pipe. How should I manage Wizards setting and goal?

Comment: Any instructions? What is asked for? Units?